# How to open a .MIG file from Windows Easy Transfer?

Tags: migration, windows-easy-transfer

Having a .mig backup file, how do I open it on Windows 8/10? They don't have the same software anymore as Windows 7 and prior used to have to open this file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems these tools don't exist natively in Windows 10.

But some say to use:

- Mike Morawski’s MigViewer.exe Utility https://www.migee.com/2011/01/17/mig-recover-and-viewer-utility-alpha/ or https://www.migee.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/?SD OR alternatively also a copy on a github project: https://github.com/TannerBrunscheon/UIUSMTGUI/raw/c58e015bf633dcd07e466c9abbdb8272ecb54e11/UIUSMTGUI/data/x86/MigViewer.exe
- Some say use the Windows ADK tool called USMT: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-extract-files-from-a-compressed-migration-store

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old Windows 7 machine, transfer the entire `migwiz` folder
to the new Windows 10 machine. This will allow you to run the wizard
and restore the data from the `.mig` file, or any other operations that the
software can do.

Select the `amd64` folder for 64-bit Windows 10, or the `x86` folder for
32-bit Windows 10. Perhaps the file to run is named `MigSetup.exe`.